# Determine the multiplicity of a root in determinant

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinant

Consider the determinant
$$\det(A(x,z))=\begin{vmatrix}1-x&1&1&1\\1&1+x&1&1\\1&1&1-z&1\\1&1&1&1+z\end{vmatrix}.$$
It is easy to see that if we write the determinant as a bivariate polynomial $p(x,z)$, then $x=0$ and $z=0$ are its roots, i.e. $p(0,z)=p(x,0)=0$. But how can we show that these roots have multiplicity 2?

Specifically, I'm interested if it is possible to determine the multiplicity of a root in a determinant without computing the determinant explicitely. One possibility would be to use the Jacobi formula to compute, e.g., $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\det(A(x,z))$, but this task seems to be even more complicated. Probably there are some tricks that allow us to make a conclusion about the multiplicity of a root with less effort?

**EDIT:** The solution is supposed to follow this scheme:

1. Show that $x=0$ ($z=0$) is a root of the polynomial.
2. Show that $x=0$ ($z=0$) is a double root of the polynomial.
3. Deduce that $p(x,z)=x^2z^2$.

It is the second item, where I have a problem.

Comment: Can you explain how "it is easy to see that ..."? (Note: Minor typo, you likely want $ x = 1$ instead of $p=1$.)

Comment: @CalvinLin, sorry, there were a couple of typos. It was supposed to be $x=z=0$.

Comment: You may prove $\det A(x, z) = \det A(-x, z)$, this should not be hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding or subtracting one row to another does not change the value of the determinant. So $$\det\begin{bmatrix}1-x&1&1&1\\1&1+x&1&1\\1&1&1-z&1\\1&1&1&1+z\end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1+z\\0&x&0&-z\\0&0&z&z\\0&0&x&x+xz\end{bmatrix}=x^2z^2$$

NB It is $x=0$ and $z=0$ that are the roots of the polynomial.

---

EDIT: Let's expand $\det(A(x))$ as a series in $x$:

$\det(A(0))=0$ since it contains a repeated column of $1$s. This shows that $x=0$ is a root of $p(x,z)$.

To get the first order terms in $x$, recall that determinants are linear in each column separately, hence expanding the first and second columns gives \begin{align}\det(A(x))&=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1+x&1&1\\1&1&1-z&1\\1&1&1&1+z\end{bmatrix}-\det\begin{bmatrix}x&1&1&1\\0&1+x&1&1\\0&1&1-z&1\\0&1&1&1+z\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&1\\1&x&1&1\\1&0&1-z&1\\1&0&1&1+z\end{bmatrix}-\det\begin{bmatrix}x&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&1&1-z&1\\0&1&1&1+z\end{bmatrix}-\det\begin{bmatrix}x&0&1&1\\0&x&1&1\\0&0&1-z&1\\0&0&1&1+z\end{bmatrix}\\
&=-x^2\det\begin{bmatrix}1-z&1\\1&1+z\end{bmatrix}\end{align} In the second equation, the first two determinants cancel out by noticing that the second can be obtained from the first by swapping the first two columns and rows. It is this cancellation that annihilates the $x$ term and produces the double root $x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and thank you for pointing at the typos. However, I'm supposed to provide a specific step as indicated in the EDIT part. Your solution does not seem to address that...

Comment: @orthxx It wasn't clear from the question. I've tried to address that specific step in the answer.

Comment: thank you for expanding your answer. However, your solution shows that x=0 is a double root by merely factoring it from the determinant. That is to say, you first find the determinant and then conclude about the multiplicity of the root by looking at it. I thought that there is some more intrinsic way to do so. In particular, I used the Jacobi formula to compute the derivative of $\det(A)$ w.r.t. $x$ and it gives $2xz^2$ as expected. But using Jacobi formula is probably even more time-consuming than computing determinant by some brut force procedure (e.g. Laplace expansion).